# Best practice for SOLR partial index in order to update attributes that change frequently in Hybris

Tags: java, indexing, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

**My scenario is like this.
Solr Indexing happens for a product and then product approval status is made unapproved from backoffice. After then, when you search the related words that is placed in description of the product or directly product code from website, you get a server error since the product that is made unapproved is still placed in solr.**

If you perform any type of indexing from backoffice manually, it works again. But it is not a good solution since there might be lots of products whose status is changed or that is not a solution which happens instantly. If you use cronjob for indexing, that is not a fast solution again.You get server error until cronjob starts to work.

**I would like to update solr index instantly for the attributes which changes frequently like price, status, etc.** For instance, when an attribute changes, Is it a good way to start partial index immediately in java code? If it is, how? (by IndexerService?). For another solution, Is it a better idea to make http request to solr for the attribute?
In summary, I am looking for the best solution to perform partial index.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For this case you need to write two new important SOLR-Configuration parts:

1) A new **SOLR-Cronjob** that trigger the indexing

2) A new **SOLR-IndexerQuery** for indexing with your special requirements.

When you have a look at the default stuff from hybris you see:

```
INSERT_UPDATE CronJob;code[unique=true];job(code);singleExecutable;sessionLanguage(isocode);active;
;backofficeSolrIndexerUpdateCronJob;backofficeSolrIndexerUpdateJob;false;en;false;

INSERT Trigger;cronJob(code);active;activationTime;year;month;day;hour;minute;second;relative;weekInterval;daysOfWeek;
;backofficeSolrIndexerUpdateCronJob;true;;-1;-1;-1;-1;-1;05;false;0;;
```

This part above is to configure when the job should run. You can modify him, that he should run ever 5 seconds for example.

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexerQuery; solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique = true]; identifier[unique = true]; type(code); injectCurrentDate[default = true]; injectCurrentTime[default = true]; injectLastIndexTime[default = true]; query; user(uid)   
; $solrIndexedType ; $solrIndexedType-updateQuery ; update ; false ; false ; false ; "SELECT DISTINCT {PK} FROM {Product AS p JOIN VariantProduct AS vp ON {p.PK}={vp.baseProduct}  } WHERE {p.modifiedtime} >= ?lastStartTimeWithSuccess OR {vp.modifiedtime} >= ?lastStartTimeWithSuccess" ; admin
```

The second part here is the more important. Here you define which products should be indexed. Here you can see that the UPDATE-Job is looking for every Product that was modified. Here you could write a new FlexibleSearch with your special requirements.

> **tl;tr Answear:** You have to write a new performant solrIndexerQuery that could be trigger every 5 seconds